# Decrease of $L_1$ norm of piecewise constant functions after some "averaging"

Tags: real-analysis, functions

In the course of a project, I ended up looking at what happens to the $L_1$ of real-valued piecewise-constant functions after some particular king of smoothing — but am currently stuck at a particular step. Essentially, my question boils down to the following general
statement:
Let $f$ be a piecewise-constant function over $[0,N]$ with $\int_{[0,N]} f = 0$, and let $\mathcal{I}$ be a
partition $\mathcal{I}=(I_1,...,I_k)$ of $[0,N]$ with $I_j=[x_j, x_{j+1})$ proving it.
For any other partition $\mathcal{J}=(J_1,...,J_\ell)$ (with $J_j=[y_j, y_{j+1}))$, let
$\bar{f}_\mathcal{J}$ be the "flattening" of $f$ (resp. g) wrt $\mathcal{J}$,
that is
$$
\bar{f}_{\mathcal{J}}(x) = \sum_{j=1}^\ell \mathbb{1}_{J_j}(x) \frac{1}{y_{j+1}-y_j}\int_{y_j}^{y_{j+1}} f(t)dt
$$
($y_1=0$, $y_{\ell+1}=N$)
It is not hard to show that the $L_1$ norm $\lVert \bar{f}_{\mathcal{J}} \rVert_1$ is at most $\lVert f \rVert_1$.
However, can we be more specific and get either

- an exact explicit relation, depending on all the variables $x_i$'s,
  $y_j$'s, etc) between $\lVert \bar{f}_{\mathcal{J}} \rVert_1$ and $\lVert f \rVert_1$?
- an exact explicit relation for specific $\mathcal{I}$ and $\mathcal{J}$, i.e. both of the
  form $\operatorname{length}(I_j) = N\frac{ (1+a)^{j+1}-1 }{(1+a)^k-1}$ and $\operatorname{length}(J_j) = N\frac{ (1+b)^{j+1}-1 }{(1+b)^\ell-1}$ for $1 > b > a > 0$ (as the partition proposed in [Birge87])?
- same as above, but only an upperbound of the form
  $$ \lVert \bar{f}_{\mathcal{J}} \rVert_1 < (1-\phi(a,b))\lVert f \rVert_1 $$
  for some positive function $\phi$?

(if you have any idea or pointers -- the latter in case it has been
studied already...)

Thank you,

Clément

[Birge87] Birge, Lucien. *On the Risk of Histograms for Estimating
Decreasing Densities.* The Annals of Statistics 15 (1987), no. 3,
1013--1022. doi:10.1214/aos/1176350489.
http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1176350489.

Comment: If $\mathcal{J}$ is a refinement of $\mathcal{I}$, flattening $f$ does not change it. Also, flattening with respect to the trivial partition $\mathcal{J}=\{[0,1]\}$ will give you a function that is constant zero. So I'm not sure there is much hope of a bound of the kind you mention in the last bullet point.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: but in the last bullet/question, taking $a\neq b$ never results in a refinement (nor the trivial partition in only one element, unless $a$ is something like $N$).